# RubaXa jquery.fileapi setting preview el class

Tags: jquery, fileapi

it is possible to set dynamically the class of the element that contain the preview of file based of the file type? 
For example for image file have:

```
preview:{"width":100,"height":100,"el":".image-div-class"}...
```

and for txt file have

```
preview:{"width":100,"height":100,"el":".text-div-class"}...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append not image files type to different div need to use:

```
preview:{"width":100,"height":100,"el":".image-div-class""get":
               function ($el, file) {
                   $el.appendTo(".file-type-'+file.name.split('.').pop()+'").append("<p>"+file.name+"</p>");;
               }}
```